# How to recalculate and adjust the entire row of time in and time out in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, stored-procedures, trigger

In SN = 1, I have an original schedule of 09:15:59 with my first time in is 09:50:57 so that I am late about 34 mins. In SN=2, 13:27:05 is my time out. In SN=4, I time in again of 15:40:13 that gives me a missing time of 133 mins as you can see in SN=3. My problem now is how can I readjust or update all the table row I insert an official business time between 13:30:00 AND 15:00:00 like the output in table below...

[image: Attendance Schedule Table]

[image: This will be the output if I insert the OB time of 13:30:00 TO 15:00:00]

This will be the output if I insert the OB time of 13:30:00 TO 15:00:00

Comment: What version of SQL Server you are using? please tag it and share some sample records.

Comment: SQL SERVER 2012 ENTERPRISE EDITION

Comment: It seem interesting but it is not exactly clear.give atleast example and its desire output in textual format.